# Tensor power- Notation question

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I have a notational question, which is written usually in papers, but I can not figure it out what could be. Let $M$ be an $A$-module. I have seen this notation 
$$M^{\otimes -n}$$

I think this would mean $Hom_A(M^{\otimes n},A)$, but in other way this usually is denoted by $(M^{\otimes n})^*$. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the other answer was describing the [Picard group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_group) of a commutative ring A.  If *M* is a finitely generated projective *A*-module of rank 1, then the tensor product *M* ⊗<sub>*A*</sub> Hom<sub>*A*</sub>(*M*, *A*) is isomorphic to *A*.  In particular, the set of isomorphism classes of finitely generated projective modules of rank 1 forms a group under tensor product.

If *A* is an integral domain, then the *M* we consider are just the isomorphism classes of projective modules that are isomorphic to ideals of *A*.  This forms the ideal class group.

In particular for principal ideal domains or fields, this is not a useful concept.

Also, none of this works for general modules, not even finitely generated projective modules of rank larger than 1, so I would be very cautious of assuming this is true for a negative tensor power of some random module.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. If you're curious, the reason for that notation is that you can view the set of isomorphism classes of A-modules as a group, with the operation of tensor product. Since $M \otimes M^*$ is isomorphic to $A$, we write $M^{-1} = M^*$, and similarly for products.

Comment: M⊗Hom(M,A) is not usually isomorphic to A.  It's not even true when A is a field.